# EF6 Code First Pluralizing Tables Invalid Object Name

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

EF6 is pluralizing my Code First table names no matter what I do. I am getting the error that it can't find the pluralized table {"Invalid object name 'dbo.TestStats'."}. The table is singular in the DB as dbo.TestStat

I tried removing the convention by

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
```

I have also mapped it to the singular table name

```
    public TestStatMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.TestStatId);

        this.ToTable("TestStat");
```

I have even tried adding this to the OnModelCreating override

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TestStat>().ToTable("TestStat");
```

Here is the table that I am trying to map it to, which was generated by the EF power tools. What else can I try or what am I missing?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestStat] (
[TestStatId] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
[SeasonID] [int],
[TeamID] [int],
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.TestStat] PRIMARY KEY ([TestStatId])
```

)

Comment: Did you try Table attribute? [Table("TestStat")]

Comment: Figured out my own mistake. I have two Context classes, one inheriting from the other for the repository, and I had the code below in the base context, when I moved it to the derived it now works.

    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

Comment: So put that as your answer, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out my own mistake. I have two Context classes, one inheriting from the other for the repository, and I had the code below in the base context, when I moved it to the derived it now works. `modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();`

Answer (score -1):

if using .net 4.5 remove this line from `app.config/web.config`

```xml
 <startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" /></startup>
```

Comment: @anthony you edited text out of the code block but you left it as a snippet :/